# What does extra food production do?

Tags: endless-space

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any reason to continue exploiting food production once my planet has reached maximum population?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/76069/is-there-any-reason-to-continue-exploiting-food-production-once-my-planet-has-re)

Are there any benefits besides more people faster? Once the population of a system is full, should I scrap them to save money? I'm about 2/3rds of the way through a game, and I have 5 different food related system improvements I can build. I don't see the point, but I figure there must be one or there wouldn't be that many options available.